# Node.js Cheerio returning empty with no errors

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

i am trying to get data from table with structure like this:

```
<table id="ros_table" class="info" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
        <th>Forth</th>
        <th>Fifth</th>
        <th>Six</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#">120241</a></td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#">69801:001:0255</a></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td><span style="white-space: nowrap;">90400 m<sup>2</sup></span> <span style="white-space: nowrap;">(9.04 ha)</span></td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;">jah</td>
    </tr>
```

And the code im useing is this:

```
fetchData(url).then( (res) => {
    const html = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const statsTable = $('.table#ros_table > tr');
    statsTable.each(function() {
        let title = $(this).find('td').text();
        console.log(title);
    });
})

async function fetchData(url){
    console.log("Looking for stuff you need...")
    // Make the call
    let response = await axios(url).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    if(response.status !== 200){
        console.log("Blah, this did not work out");
        return;
    }
    return response;
}
```

It works fine with just a simple que, but for some reason i can get it to work for this table.

Comment: If the html is empty it's an issue with whatever request library you use, not cheerio.

Comment: Like i side, it works fine for a simple que and i get the data, but i cant get it to work with this table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` something out of each `.then()` block, i assume you want something like this?:

```
fetchData(url).then( (res) => {
    const html = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const statsTable = $('.table#ros_table > tr');
    return statsTable.map(function() {
        return $(this).find('td').text();
    });
})
```

Comment: Does not change anything, still empty. How can i check if the page itself maybe is bloking the request from outside?

Comment: That would result in an error i guess. Perhaps issue lies in object you are trying to access? Try `console.log($(this))` in map and see if you get any value. if not try passing element though map function: `.map(function(el) { return $(el)...}`